# How to persist a Map using JPA / Hibernate Annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, collections, annotations, mapping

[image: Table Structure]

I'm having problems persisting the above relationship using JPA 1.0 Annotations.

I can map it using the following XML which works perfectly:

```
<class name="Exposure" table="Exposures">
    <id name="id" column="Id"/>
    <property name="name" column="name" not-null="true"/>

    <set name="rules" table="ExposureRules" lazy="true" cascade="all, delete-orphan">
        <key column="TypeId"/>
        <one-to-many class="ExposureRule"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="ExposureRule" table="ExposureRules">
    <id name="id" column="Id"/>
    <property name="inclusive" column="Inclusive" not-null="true"/>

    <map name="attributes" table="ExposureRuleAttributes" lazy="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="RuleId"/>
        <index column="Attribute" type="string"/>
        <element column="Value" type="string"/>
    </map>
</class>
```

When I try to persist it using Annotations I get the following error:

```
Foreign key (FKA635AE7A4160E727:ExposureRuleAttributes [RuleId])) must have same number of 
columns as the referenced primary key (ExposureRules [TypeId,rules_id])
```

I think the problem is how I've Annotated the *attributes* Map in the *ExposureRules* class, but I can't figure out the correct way to do it?

**Exposure Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Exposures")
public class Exposure {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    @JoinTable(name="ExposureRules", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TypeId")})
    private Set<ExposureRule> rules;
```

**ExposureRule Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ExposureRules")
public class ExposureRule {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int inclusive;

    @CollectionOfElements(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="ExposureRuleAttributes",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="RuleId"))
    @IndexColumn(name="Attribute")
    @Column(name="Value")
    private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: I removed the Exposure class as a test and it works. So it looks like it's my mapping of the Set "rules" in Exposure class must be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was the following line with the @JoinTable:

```
@JoinTable(name="ExposureRules", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TypeId")})
```

I just needed a @JoinColumn like so:

```
@JoinColumn(name="TypeId")
```